# TortoiseSVN and Subclipse icons not updating with SVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I have a repository on a network share with working directories on two separate machines.  Upon making changes to my local working directory and committing them, the icons are not changing on the other developer's machine.

If the Dev goes to Team > Synchronize with Repository it shows the changes in the Synchronize view within Eclipse, however I was expecting the icon next to the project to change if it is not in sync with the repository.

The same happens with TortoiseSVN in Windows Explorer.  If we right click and check the repository for modifications it shows them, however the overlay icon on the directory is still the green check box.

Am I just misinterpreting what I expect to happen, or is there a way to get these icons to change if the project is no longer in sync with the repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icons should not change.  Working copies are not connected to each other.  The icons show the status of that working copy.  Subversion client is largely disconnected from the server.  A connection is only needed when reading or writing from the repository.  Performance would be horrible if the client was constantly talking to the server.

Using the command line, svn status -u is the command to see when there are changes on the server that are not in the working copy.  In Subclipse, this is the Synchronize action and TortoiseSVN has the Check for Modifications action which then has a button to check the repository.